# Django ORM inner join with table sharing the same foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, inner-join

I have three tables:

```
Table 1 : order
Fields: id, client_reference, price and status
(status is a foreignkey linked to order_status.id)

Table 2 : order_status 
Fields: id, lastupdate

Table 3 : order_status_i18n
Fields: id, order_status_id, language and label
(order_status_id is also a foreignkey linked to order_status.id)
```

what I'd like to do is to get the `order_status_i18n` `label` instead of `order_status_id` based on the user language, so the SQL request would be like:

```
SELECT o.client_reference as reference, o_s_i18n.label 
FROM 
order AS o 
INNER JOIN order_status_i18n AS o_s_i18n 
ON o.status=o_s_i18n.order_status_id WHERE o_s_i18n.language='the language';
```

and the Model for order contains a foreignkey attribute linked to the `order_status model` but not `order_status_i18n`, so I tried to use

```
Order.objects.filter(some_filters).prefetch_related('status')
.filter(status__in=OrderStatusI18N.objects.filter(language='the_language'))
```

Which gives me a queryset conflict telling me that I should use the queryset for `OrderStatus` rather than `OrderStatusI18N` and I totally agree to this.

But anyway, what would be the good way to manage such a request using django ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the thing.

```
Order.objects.filter(some_filters).prefetch_related('status').annotate(i18_label=F('status__order_status_i18n__language')).filter(status__order_status_i18n__language='en')
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and sorry for the delay, I check it now

Comment: Thanks it works, not simple at the beginning to understand the trick with annotations, after playing with it a bit in the django shell I figured out.